# Yum command to find files that an RPM will deploy

Tags: centos, redhat, yum

On Ubuntu/Debian you can run

```
apt-file list nginx-core
```

and you will get a list of all the files that a package will deploy when installed.

How can I achieve this in RHEL with the `yum` command ?

The command `rpm -ql` is not an option because it only works with already installed packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK `rpm` can list the content of "remote" package. You just need to use the full URL. For example:

```
rpm -ql https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/baseos/latest/x86_64/getPackage/audit-3.0-0.10.20180831git0047a6c.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

will list the content of audit package from Oracle Linux 8

If you install `yum-utils` package you can use command like:

```
repoquery -l audit
```

to get list of the files in package (even if it's not installed)

Comment: This is not a good solution for normal workflow. I need 3 minutes to find the repository where the package is, find its URL, construct it properly, then run the command. `yum info` seems to provide some information about the RPM, but not information about the files that it will deploy.

Comment: @Subzero123, it depend of the target! In UNIX/Linux usually you have many ways to do particular task. See my edited answer

Comment: I used to download packages and inspect them with `rpm -qlp`. `repoquery -l audit` works great, thanks